# Javascript - string capitalization function throwing strange error

Tags: javascript, string

Stackers, please help my worn out beginner's brain and let me know where I've goofed.

My function accepts a lower case string as its only argument. It is SUPPOSED to return the same string with all even indexed characters in each word uppercase. But the actual output is different to my expected output.

For example:

```js
console.log(toWeirdCase('harry enjoys reading books'))
//expected output: 'HaRrY EnJoYs ReAdInG BoOkS'
// actual output: 'HaRrY EnJoYs ReAdInG BookS'

console.log(toWeirdCase('gooooooogle search in vain'));
//expected output: 'GoOoOoOoGlE SeArCh In VaIn'
// actual output: GoooooooGlE SeArCh In VaIn

function toWeirdCase(string) {
    string = string.split(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < string[i].length; x++) {
            if (string[i].indexOf(string[i].charAt(x)) % 2 == 0) {
                string[i] = string[i].replace(string[i].charAt(x), string[i].charAt(x).toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    }
    return string.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Do any of the answers suit your needs? Could you give some feed-back or accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

When you look up a character with `indexOf`, you'll get the index of the *first* occurrence, not necessarily the one you were initially looking at. Similarly, `replace` (when given a string value as first argument) will replace the *first* occurrence, not necessarily the one you are interested in.

Here is a fix, without changing too much your original:

```js
function toWeirdCase(string){
    string = string.split(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i<string.length; i++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < string[i].length; x++) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {  
                // Only modify the single character of interest. The rest is sliced in
                string[i] = string[i].slice(0, x) + string[i][x].toUpperCase() + string[i].slice(x+1);
            }
        }
    }
    return string.join(" ");
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('harry enjoys reading books')) 
console.log(toWeirdCase('gooooooogle search in vain'));
```

#### Alternative

You could also approach it differently and not split the string into words, but just reset a flag when you see a space. 
Here you can see that idea implemented using `reduce`, resulting in a *functional programming*  style solution:

```js
function toWeirdCase(string){
    return [...string].reduce(
        ([str, j], c, i) => c === " " || j ? [str + c, 0] : [str + c.toUpperCase(), 1],
        ["", 0]
    )[0];
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('harry enjoys reading books')) 
console.log(toWeirdCase('gooooooogle search in vain'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your code has an issue when you are using the same characters consecutively. They have been properly explained by the previous two answers.

```js
function toWeirdCase(string){

  string = string.split(" ");
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i<string.length; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < string[i].length; x++) {    
      if (x%2 == 0) {
        result.push(string[i].charAt(x).toUpperCase())
      } else {
        result.push(string[i].charAt(x).toLowerCase())
      }
    }
  result.push(" ")
  }
  return result.join(" ");
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('gooooooogle search in vain'));
```

Comment: True...that I didn't fully notice.. yes, in this case, two loops would be necessary, a loop over words, and a second loop over each word's characters.

Comment: updated my answer to at least match the OP's logic..not the prettiest but it works. thanks @trincot for comment..prefer your alternative solution.