# upperCase even characters and lowerCase odd characters in each element of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting

I need to upperCase even characters and lowerCase odd characters in each element of an array so that with the input of 'This is a test' the output would be 'ThIs Is A TeSt' (excluding spaces so that each word begins with a capital letter).

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
  var reg = /\b(?![\s.])/
  var res = string.split(reg)
  var newArr = []

  for (let k = 0; k < res.length; k++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < res[k].length; j++) {
      if (j % 2 == 0) {
        res[k].charAt(j).toUpperCase()
      } else {
        res[k].charAt(j).toLowerCase()
      }
    }
    newArr.push(res[k])
  }
  return newArr.join('')
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('This is a test'))
```

It doesn't work as intended and due to lack of experience I can't tell what's missing. Could you please help me out with this? Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468121/javascript-string-capitalization-function-throwing-strange-error/53468231#53468231

Comment: Your code operates on odd/even letters in each word, not in the string. Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toUpperCase` doesn't modify the string in place (JavaScript strings are immutable). You need to assign the result back to a variable.

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
  var reg = /\b(?![\s.])/
  var res = string.split(reg)
  var newArr = []

  for (let k = 0; k < res.length; k++) {
    let newString = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < res[k].length; j++) {
      if (j % 2 == 0) {
        newString += res[k].charAt(j).toUpperCase()
      } else {
        newString += res[k].charAt(j).toLowerCase()
      }
    }
    newArr.push(newString)
  }
  return newArr.join('')
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('This is a test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replace()` with an external variable to decide if the text should be upper or lower case:

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
  let uppercase = true;
  return string
    .replace(/./g, c => {
      const current = uppercase;
      
      uppercase = c === ' ' ? true : !uppercase;
    
      return current ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase();
    });
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('This is a test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Golfier version:

```
input
  .split(/\s+/)
  .map(wrd => wrd
    .split('')
    .map((c, i) => i % 2 ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase())
    .join(''))
  .join(' ');
```

If you don't care about line length, it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a basic map to achieve this, and then use modules to choose upper/lower case odd/even values

1. Split each word
2. Split each letter in each word

   1. Use modulus on the word, not the sentence
3. Join the word back together
4. Join the sentence back together

```js
function toWeirdCase(str){
  return str.split(' ').map(word =>
    word.split('').map((itm, idx) => idx % 2 ? itm.toLowerCase() : itm.toUpperCase()).join('')
  ).join(' ')
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('This is a test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```js
let str = "This is a test";

let op = str.split(' ').map((a,i)=>a.split('').map((e,i)=>i%2==0 ? e.toUpperCase() : e.toLowerCase()).join('')).join(' ');

console.log(op)
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` and `String.split`, `String.join` to get that result.
Map through the words and then trough each character and if even uppercase it else lowercase it.

```js
const up = string => 
  string.split(' ')
  .map(word => word.split('')
    .map((chr, i) => chr[i%2 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']()).join('')
  ).join(' ')

console.log(up('This is a test'))
```

You can also solve it with only one `Array.map` and `Array.reduce`:

```js
const chg = wrd => wrd.split('').map((c,i) => c[i%2 ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase']()).join('')
const up = str => str.split(' ').reduce((r,c) => r.concat(' ', chg(c)), '')

console.log(up('This is a test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple map function to do that:

```
"This is a test"
   .split("")
   .map((s, i) => (i % 2 == 0 ? s.toUpperCase() : s))
   .join("");
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)